# Cordova ionic inappbrowser sdktargetversion 23 to 26 exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, android-fileprovider

I'm using IONIC Cordova and I have a problem when I pass targetSdkVersion 23 to 26.

Here is my problem :

I use :

```
import {InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
```

In My constructor I have :

```
fileService: File, private iab: InAppBrowser
```

And after I download a file and write it in

```
this.fileService.externalDataDirectory
```

after I do this :

```
this.iab.create(this.fileService.externalDataDirectory + fileName, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

And inappbrowser app is openning and show me the file.

But when I pass to targetSdkVersion 26, I got this erreor:

```
D/InAppBrowser: target = _system
D/InAppBrowser: in system
D/InAppBrowser: InAppBrowser: Error loading url file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app/files/file.pdf:android.os.FileUriExposedException: 
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app/files/file.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

Can someone help me to solve this? I see that I need to change my manifest file to add a provider but I'm not sure how to do this and which plugin I need to add in my project to tranform it.